# Top label cut off on D3 chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

D3 newbie here. Simple question. I have a donut chart with labels on the outside. The top label is getting cut out since the SVG is too small. I've expanded the SVG padding on the other sides but not sure how to increase it on the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/qA6t6/9/

```
      var w = 400,
          h = 400,
          r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
          labelr = r + 30, // radius for label anchor
          donut = d3.layout.pie(),
          arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r * .6).outerRadius(r);

      var vis = d3.select(".impact-chart")
        .append("svg:svg")
          .data([data])
          .attr("width", w + 175)
          .attr("height", h + 35);

      var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
          .data(donut.value(function(d) { return d.val }))
        .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "arc")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 80) + "," + r + ")");

      var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .range(["#C1B398", "#605951", "#FBEEC2", "#61A6AB", "#ACCEC0", "#bbb"]);

      arcs.append("svg:path")
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
          .attr("d", arc);

      arcs.append("svg:text")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              var c = arc.centroid(d),
                  x = c[0],
                  y = c[1],
                  // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
                  h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
              return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
                 (y/h * labelr) +  ")"; 
          })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
              // are we past the center?
              return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
                  "end" : "start";
          })
          .text(function(d, i) { return d.data.name;});
```

Comment: See my edited answer to your previous question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22237336/1082169

Answer (score 1):

Your translate attribute for your chart is setting it at the top of the svg element. There is an offset for the x position but not the y...

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 80) + "," + r + ")");
```

What you need to do is add an offset:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 80) + "," + (r + 80) + ")");
```

Or, you can centre it:

```
attr("transform", "translate(" + 1.5*r + "," + 1.5*r + ")")
```